# Python allows for instances of the same class to have different sets of methods. Is it appropriate to have instances with different methods?

Tags: python

Python allows for methods to be add to instances of a class rather than the whole class as demonstrated her [Adding a Method to an Existing Object Instance](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/972/adding-a-method-to-an-existing-object-instance). Most of the time this seems like a bad idea for consistent behavior of classes. When might this be necessary? Why does python allow this at all?

Answer (score 1):

Python doesn't specifically allow this, it's just a consequence of the way the Python object model works. Methods are just object attributes like any other; and generally you can add any attribute to an existing object.

Comment: ahh. So this feature was not included for a purpose but rather is a side effect of the implementation of python as a language? (and there for I should not do this....?)

Comment: Feel free to do it. There are certainly cases when it is useful, for example monkey-patching and especially mocking in tests.

Comment: @Francis it's a consequence of the object model, not really the implementation. Generally, Python sticks to the notion that "we are all consenting adults", and doesn't protect you from doing silly things. I sometimes do it when I'm trying to debug / write a method in a REPL, but never in production code. Perhaps there are valid use-cases in mocking/testing, but other than that, I don't encounter them.

Comment: @Francis - I wouldn't express it that way. The creator of Python was surely aware of the consequences of whatever object model he chose. Therefore, if he had felt it was "sufficiently important" to *prevent* different instances of the same class from having different methods, then he would have chosen an object model accordingly. What I am saying is, he might not have had any specific use case in mind, but he also clearly didn't want to close that door. The resulting behavior is not a "side effect". There is certainly nothing accidental or unintended about it.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. So its more of a laiz fair, "use at your own risk" model